# Average Speed Calculation

Tags: divisibility

An airplane leaves New York at 1:10 PM and arrives in Miami, 1125 miles away, at 3:40 PM. What is its average speed in miles per hour?

Isn't the formula speed = distance/time?
It didn't work for me though, I got about 700 MPH.

Comment: $450 \times 2.5 = 1125$ as a hint. Try finding miles traveled per minute and then converting minutes into hours.

Answer (score 0):

I see my mistake. I did 1125/1.5, when it's supposed to be 2.5. A simple math error.
The answer is 450.

Comment: I suggest you delete the question, before you get downvoted and lose your reputation.

Comment: How? Where's the option?